# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, firebase

This error below appeared on my CountDown App and all my code is correct as I am following a youtube Tutorial. I tried updating my Gradle and checked compiler issues on the web. How can I resolve this ??

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.countdowntimerapp, PID: 28507 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference at com.example.countdowntimerapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506) at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194) at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483) at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29335) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)`

Here is the code from the main activity. Debugging has been attempted and most of the code had been commented to check where the problem lies.

````
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;
     private TextView mTextViewCountdown;
     private Button mButtonStartPause;
     private Button mButtonReset;
     private CountDownTimer mCountdownTimer;
     private Boolean mTimerRunning;
     private long mTimeLeftInMills = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextViewCountdown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mTimerRunning){
                    pauseTimer();
                }
                else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });
        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });
        updateCountdownText();
    }
    private void startTimer() {
        mCountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMills, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millsLeftUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMills = millsLeftUntilFinished;
                updateCountdownText();
            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
              mTimerRunning = false;
              mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
              mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountdownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMills = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountdownText();
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void updateCountdownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMills / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMills / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountdown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

}```
````

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the line at which the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Creating variables has 2 steps:

1. Declaration - give the variable a name and a type(int, String etc...)
2. Initialization - give the variable a value (a number for int, true/false for boolean, and so on)

Your code declares a variable:

```
private Boolean mTimerRunning;
```

but initialize it first only in the startTimer() function:

```
 private void startTimer() {
    mCountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMills, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millsLeftUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMills = millsLeftUntilFinished;
            updateCountdownText();
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          mTimerRunning = false;
          mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
          mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();
    
    //here
    mTimerRunning = true;

    mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

When you touch the mButtonStartPause button to start the timer in the first time, your code should call the startTimer() function.
To do that you check the value of mTimerRunning, **but there is no any value there**. The value will be set only in startTimer().

You need to give a value to the mTimerRunning variable before you try to use it.
The error happened because you tried to use something that doesn't exist.

Fix it by giving a value (false) to mTimerRunning right when you declare it:

```
...
private CountDownTimer mCountdownTimer;

//fix
private Boolean mTimerRunning = false;

private long mTimeLeftInMills = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS ;
...
```